# Was bedeuten die Buchstaben "i", "x" oder "d" zusätzlich zu "m" und "w" in Stellenanzeigen?

Tags: abbreviation, gender-neutrality

Ich habe in der Zeitung die Stellenangebote durchgeblättert und bin dabei über verschiedene Abkürzungen gestolpert. Einige Angebote hatten ein "(m/w/d)" stehen, andere ein "(m/w/x)". Ich habe auch "(m/w/i)" und nur "(m/w)" gesehen.

Was das Letzte bedeutet, ist ja in [dieser Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/32107/what-does-m-f-or-m-w-mean-in-german-job-postings/32108#32108) beleuchtet. Aber was bedeutet das i? Und was bedeutet das x? Dasselbe wie auch das d?

Comment: https://personalmarketing2null.de/2018/02/m-w-divers-stellenanzeigen/

Comment: Note that, with the typical sarcasm found at many workplaces, "m/w/d" is sometimes mockingly read as "männlich, weiß, deutsch", which might be intended to expose the assumed true intensions of a hypocritical HR department.

Answer (score 10):

Vor einiger Zeit hat das oberste deutsche Gericht entschieden, dass Formulare, die das Geschlecht abfragen, eine dritte Option anbieten müssen. (Vergleiche dazu [die Pressemitteilung des BVerfG](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Pressemitteilungen/DE/2017/bvg17-095.html) und das [Urteil 1 BvR 2019/16](https://www.bundesverfassungsgericht.de/SharedDocs/Entscheidungen/DE/2017/10/rs20171010_1bvr201916.html;jsessionid=3C9982A3B4494B427AF8F6F04DC50363.2_cid392).)

Diese ist für intersex-Personen oder Personen, die sich weder dem männlichen noch dem weiblichen Geschlecht zugehörig fühlen, gedacht.

Das x und das i stehen hier für "**i**nterse**x**". Das d steht für "divers".

Es existiert hier im Deutschen noch keine gefestigte Terminologie, deswegen hat dazu jeder Arbeitgeber seine eigene Formulierung.

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass "x" für das x in Intersex steht, sondern eher als neutraler Platzhalter in Anlehnung an z.B. Professx.